# Tailwind in React/Next.js doesn't generate css for text-*xl classes if variable is used in className

Tags: reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

I've wanted to create React Title component with Tailwind where you can pass level (H1-H6 or make it DIV if empty) and pass size (1-9 for text-xl to text-9xl).

For example, I can have reusable component like this:

```
// Reusable component:
<Title level={2} size={4}>Test title</Title>
// Which renders to:
<h2 className="text-4xl">Test title</h2>
```

I can see those classes in Inspector and I can also see that there is no .font-4xl css generated for the project. So the title stays in default font-size.
However, if I add any test text like `<div class="text-4xl">test</div>` then it will generate css and it will also apply it to  component. This can be repeated for all 9 sizes.

Is there a way how to make Tailwind generate css only when used (great for minimal file size) but also having some kind of clean code for the component?

Right now, my idea is to have all common classes applied in reusable Title component but always add desired size (text-*xl) only when using it.

```
const Title = ({ children, className, style, level, size }) => {
  const commonClass = 'font-extrabold uppercase mb-4';

  const fontSize = size ? `text-${size}xl` : `text-${level}xl`;

  switch (level) {
    case 1:
      return (
        <h1 className={`${fontSize} ${commonClass}`} style={style}>
          {children}
        </h1>
      );
    case 2:
      return (
        <h2 className={`${fontSize} ${commonClass}`} style={style}>
          {children}
        </h2>
      );
    case 3:
      return (
        <h3 className={`${fontSize} ${commonClass}`} style={style}>
          {children}
        </h3>
      );
    case 4:
      return (
        <h4 className={`${fontSize} ${commonClass}`} style={style}>
          {children}
        </h4>
      );
    case 5:
      return (
        <h5 className={`${fontSize} ${commonClass}`} style={style}>
          {children}
        </h5>
      );
    case 6:
      return (
        <h6 className={`${fontSize} ${commonClass}`} style={style}>
          {children}
        </h6>
      );
    default:
      return (
        <div className={`${fontSize} ${commonClass}`} style={style}>
          {children}
        </div>
      );
  }
};

export default Title;
```

Comment: try `styled-components`, basically you need to have a localized css. This is normally referred as css-in-js. Search around and pick any of the open library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the Tailwind docs on the [`JIT mode`](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode) on Dynamic values

> ### Dynamic values
>
> Note that you still need to write purgeable HTML when
> using arbitrary values, and your classes need to exist as complete
> strings for Tailwind to detect them correctly.
>
> **Don't use string concatenation to create class names**
>
> ```
> <div className={`mt-[${size === 'lg' ? '22px' : '17px' }]`}></div>
> ```
>
> Tailwind doesn’t include any sort of client-side runtime, so class
> names need to be statically extractable at build-time, and can’t
> depend on any sort of arbitrary dynamic values that change on the
> client. Use inline styles for these situations, or combine Tailwind
> with a CSS-in-JS library like Emotion if it makes sense for your
> project

So you should uses something like, or a `switch` or `if` statement works fine.

```
const sizeArg = size ? size : level;
const fontSize = textSize === 1 ? 'text-1xl' : (sizeArg === 2 ? 'text-2xl' : (...))
```

Comment: Your example with chained ternary operator worked really well and with prettier auto-formatting it even looks clean and readable. Thanks a lot!
And as you mentioned, it was caused by JIT mode and string concatenation. I have copied my Title component from older project where I didn't use JIT mode and it basically introduced this issue but I am glad that now I understand what was wrong.